codeigniter4 session redis handler cluster problem
namespace Config;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;
use CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers;

class Session extends  BaseConfig
{
public ?string $driver = RedisHandler::class;
public string $savePath = 'tls://clusterxx.redis.xxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379?auth=password' ;
}
}

aws elastic cache (redis) is cluster. so this code give MOVED error. how can i use session cluster redis on CODEIGNITER 4
I'm trying to extend the session handler for predishandler but I haven't succeeded
